# Why next-intl does not provide a way how to define default messages directly in components?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, internationalization, next-intl

Why does [`next-intl`](https://github.com/amannn/next-intl?tab=readme-ov-file#what-does-it-look-like) (and some other react translation tools) **NOT** provide a way how to define default messages directly inside components?

For example:

`next-intl` is used like this:

```js
/* obtain the t from some hook etc. */
const content = (
  <>
    <h1>{t('title')}</h1>
    <p>{t('text')}</p>
  </>
);
```

while `react-intl`:

```js
/* import FormattedMessage from react-intl */
const content = (
  <>
    <h1><FormattedMessage id="title" defaultMessage="Hi there!" /></h1>
    <p><FormattedMessage id="text" defaultMessage="Since when is developing frontend such a pain?" /></p>
  </>
);
```

What is the reason for not having the default messages defined directly inside of componets? Is it the bundle size? If so, is there some tool that could remove the default messages from the production builds?

Adding the new keys and messages to the related jsons manually feels like a huge step back to me.

Thank you for clarification.